# I'm getting a different value from what I expect when accessing to an object's property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a trouble with getting access to an object's property.

I'm able to get access to an object's property, but I get a different value from what I expect.

This is the code I'm working on right now.

```
alertHeading.on('blur', function(){

    var inputtedVal = $(this).val();
    var key = alertMode.val();

    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(backgroundPage) {

      var background = backgroundPage.background;

      var alertObject = background.getStorage(key);

      alertObject.heading="aaa";
      alertObject.heading[0]="zero";
      alertObject.heading[1]="one";

      (1)This works fine.
      console.log(alertObject); //outputs Object {heading: "aaa"} 

      (2)These don't work as I expect.
      console.log(alertObject.heading[0]); // outputs a. I'm expecting "zero".
      console.log(alertObject.heading[1]); // outputs a. I'm expecting "one".

    });

  })
```

How am I able to get access the value I set in the line where I write "to "alertObject.heading[0]"?

Please help me out to solve this problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a string as an array and strings have the bracket syntax to access characters. This is basically what you're doing, and won't work:

```
var str = 'hello';
str[0] = 'world';

console.log(str, str[0]); //=> hello h
```

A string *literal* is not a regular object in JavaScript. If you attempt to use any object as an array, you'd still be able to access those properties but you'd be storing them in the `prototype` of that object. But again, string literals are *not* regular objects. If you follow bad practice (don't) and create a string with the `String` constructor you'd be able to access properties that don't start with a number:

```
var str = new String('hello');
str['a'] = 'world'; // or str.a = 'world'

console.log(str, str['a']); //=> hello world
```

Your logic doesn't make sense anyway, first you assign a string and then you want an array? You lost the string!. Try this:

```
alertObject.heading = ['aaa']; // initialize as array
alertObject.heading[1] = 'zero';
alertObject.heading[2] = 'one';
```

Now you have an array like `['aaa', 'zero', 'one']`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate alertObject.heading as array first, and then assign values.

What you are doing is that you create a "string" and then you access a char by index.